# Can't properly split Wi-Fi signal string by space

Tags: python, regex

I have this python script:

```
import subprocess
import csv

def wifi_sniffer(ssid=''):
    """ Perform wifi scan and calls function to export results into a CSV file. """

    cmd = 'airport -s | grep -i ' + str(ssid) if ssid <> '' else 'airport -s'
    wifi = str(subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)).split('\n')

    wifi_arr = []
    for item in wifi:
        wifi_arr.append(item.strip())

    wifi_arr.pop(0)
    export_to_csv(wifi_arr)


def export_to_csv(array):
    """ Exports wifi scan result into a CSV file. """

    array.pop(len(array)-1)

    f = open('export.csv', 'wt')
    try:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for i in array:
            #print i
            writer.writerow((str(i.split(' ')[0]), str(i.split(' ')[2])))

    finally:
        f.close()


""" Call main function. """
wifi_sniffer()
```

That is returning me these results:

```
Vix_CPD c8:d7:19:fb:97:ee -93  149,+1  Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)
Prixvisitante 0a:27:22:f3:3d:e5 -67  1       Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
Superprix 06:27:22:f3:3d:e5 -70  1       Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
Vivo 4G Plus 08:63:61:8d:95:dc -85  11      Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)
@n18u$Ch@c@l 58:8d:09:1d:c5:a1 -81  11      N  US WPA2(802.1x/AES/AES)
ASM Wifi 00:1a:3f:4b:b4:b2 -79  11      N  BR WPA(PSK/TKIP,AES/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/TKIP,AES/TKIP)
Visitantes 58:8d:09:1d:c5:a0 -79  11      N  US NONE
LEMON 74:ea:3a:fc:a9:68 -81  10,-1   Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)
Superprix 06:27:22:f3:80:9b -33  6       Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
Prixvisitante 0a:27:22:f3:80:9b -34  6       Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
```

I need to split strings to get the SSID and the signal strength, but when I split by space, SSIDs like `Vivo 4G Plus` returns me `Vivo` as index 0 and `4G` as index 2.

I need it to be `Vivo 4G Plus` as index 0 and `-85` as index 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular expression can help:

```
r'(?P<ssid>.*?)\s+(?P<mac>(?:[a-zA-Z\d]{2}:){5}[a-zA-Z\d]{2})\s+(?P<signal>[-\d]+)'
```

This'll extract the SSID, MAC address and signal strength as separate fields.

The crucial section is the `(?P<mac>...)` group; it'll only match 6 2-digit hex values separated by colons; the preceding section will then grab *everything* up until the whitespace before the MAC address, and the `(?P<signal>...)` group takes anything with digits and minus signs following after.

[Online demo at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/eB1cX5/1).

Demo in an interactive session:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = '''\
... Vix_CPD c8:d7:19:fb:97:ee -93  149,+1  Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)
... Prixvisitante 0a:27:22:f3:3d:e5 -67  1       Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
... Superprix 06:27:22:f3:3d:e5 -70  1       Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
... Vivo 4G Plus 08:63:61:8d:95:dc -85  11      Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)
... @n18u$Ch@c@l 58:8d:09:1d:c5:a1 -81  11      N  US WPA2(802.1x/AES/AES)
... ASM Wifi 00:1a:3f:4b:b4:b2 -79  11      N  BR WPA(PSK/TKIP,AES/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/TKIP,AES/TKIP)
... Visitantes 58:8d:09:1d:c5:a0 -79  11      N  US NONE
... LEMON 74:ea:3a:fc:a9:68 -81  10,-1   Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)
... Superprix 06:27:22:f3:80:9b -33  6       Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
... Prixvisitante 0a:27:22:f3:80:9b -34  6       Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
... '''.splitlines()
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<ssid>.*?)\s+(?P<mac>(?:[a-zA-Z\d]{2}:){5}[a-zA-Z\d]{2})\s+(?P<signal>[-\d]+)')
>>> for line in sample:
...     print(pattern.match(line).groupdict())
... 
{'mac': 'c8:d7:19:fb:97:ee', 'ssid': 'Vix_CPD', 'signal': '-93'}
{'mac': '0a:27:22:f3:3d:e5', 'ssid': 'Prixvisitante', 'signal': '-67'}
{'mac': '06:27:22:f3:3d:e5', 'ssid': 'Superprix', 'signal': '-70'}
{'mac': '08:63:61:8d:95:dc', 'ssid': 'Vivo 4G Plus', 'signal': '-85'}
{'mac': '58:8d:09:1d:c5:a1', 'ssid': '@n18u$Ch@c@l', 'signal': '-81'}
{'mac': '00:1a:3f:4b:b4:b2', 'ssid': 'ASM Wifi', 'signal': '-79'}
{'mac': '58:8d:09:1d:c5:a0', 'ssid': 'Visitantes', 'signal': '-79'}
{'mac': '74:ea:3a:fc:a9:68', 'ssid': 'LEMON', 'signal': '-81'}
{'mac': '06:27:22:f3:80:9b', 'ssid': 'Superprix', 'signal': '-33'}
{'mac': '0a:27:22:f3:80:9b', 'ssid': 'Prixvisitante', 'signal': '-34'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I am not very familiarised with regex I will have to think a little about how to implement it into my code, but I am sure this is the right thing to do! :)

Comment: Again, thanks for this very complete answer. Wasn't difficult to change my code and it worked perfectly! :) I do have doubts about the regex pattern but I think I'll have to start studying it hard!

Comment: @LucasRezende: I added a Regex101 demo for you; they break down the expression into an explanation tree on the right-hand side with color coding. Hopefully that'll help in understanding how the pattern works, and you can play with it and sample inputs.

Comment: @MartijinPieters, thanks again! Will take a look at it and study for a while ;)

Comment: The named groups method @MartijinPieters employed is so powerful, because it allows you to break complex expressions into readable, usable chunks with named tags. You save productivity on clarity alone. Regex is intimidating at first glance, but any time spent growing more familiar with it is time well spent.